# run arduino code without a usb cable connected to a computer

Tags: arduino

I am using sim7000E with arduino uno and i want to be able to run it without a computer. I tried to connect it only with the power supply with the correct power and again it doesn't run my code.  Does anyone know what i can do in order to fix it?

Comment: You are going to have to supply a lot more information about what you are doing for us to be able to help

Comment: `again it doesn't run my code` ... does that mean that it did not run the code before that?